# Handling state after fetching data - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a default state as shown below, I'm fetching the data from postgres, considering a situation where my **photos** array is null, the state does not get updated.

The reason is I'm accessing some of the parameters directly, `{this.state.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].url}`

What I see from actions is

`action Object {type: "FETCH_MEDIA_FULFILLED", payload: Array[1]}`

`error TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of null`

`action Object {type: "FETCH_MEDIA_REJECTED", payload: TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of null at Media.render (http://localhost:3000/clien…}`

What is the right way of doing this? While setting state should I create a default object, update all parameters and then set the state?

There is no issues if there is at least 1 array element of photos, the only problem is at the first state when the photos column is null.

State :

```
this.state = {
        media : {
            video : "",
            photos : [{
                title : "",
                url : "",
                category : {
                    interior : false,
                    exterior : true,
                    closeup : false
                },
                display : {
                    preview : false,
                    featured : true,
                    none : false
                },
                size : "",
                attribution_link : "",
                attribution_text : "",
                description : ""
            }],
            selectedMediaIndex : 0
        }
    }
```

Once the componentWillReceiveProps receives the nextProps, I'm updating my state.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){        
    if(nextProps.media.length){
        this.setState({
            media : nextProps.media[0]
        })
    }
}
```

CONNECTOR :

```
const mapStateToProps = function (store) {    
    return {
        media: store.media.media
    };
};

const PhotoConnector = Redux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Media);

export default class MediaConnector extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <PhotoConnector media={this.props.media}/>
    );
  }
}
```

REDUCER :

```
export default function reducer(
state={
    media: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
}, action) {

switch (action.type) {
  case "FETCH_MEDIA": {
    return {...state, fetching: true}
  }
  case "FETCH_MEDIA_REJECTED": {
    return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
  }
  case "FETCH_MEDIA_FULFILLED": {

    return {
      ...state,
      fetching: false,
      fetched: true,
      media: action.payload,
    }
  }
}

return state
```

}

**UPDATE**

I got a way not to get the error, I'm basically checking if the photos is null and setting a default state array to it.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.media.length){

        if(!nextProps.media.photos){                

            this.setState({
                media : {
                    video : nextProps.media[0].video,
                    photos : [{
                        title : "",
                        url : "",
                        category : {
                            interior : false,
                            exterior : true,
                            closeup : false
                        },
                        display : {
                            preview : false,
                            featured : true,
                            none : false
                        },
                        size : "",
                        attribution_link : "",
                        attribution_text : "",
                        description : ""
                    }],
                    selectedMediaIndex : 0
                }
            })
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                media : nextProps.media[0]
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Any other solution will be appreciated.

Comment: as you tag this with [react-redux], I would expect to see a reducer somewhere, is the [react-redux] tag correct?

Comment: Yes @Icepickle, sorry about that. I just updated the code with reducer.

Comment: alright, then the next question would be why you are no using connected components?

Comment: @Icepickle I just updated the question again with adding `CONNECTOR` is that what you were talking about?

Comment: You shouldn't setState in componentWillReceiveProps. In redux the only source for the state are reducers.

Comment: @GiorgioBozio Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why to not just have default props?

```
PhotoConnector.defaultProps = {
  media: {
    video: [],
    photos: [],
  }
};
```

Or maybe default store?

```
class Media {
  constructor(js = {}) {
    this.video = js.video || [];
    this.photos = js.photos || [];
  }
}

state={
  media: [new Media()],
}

case "FETCH_MEDIA_FULFILLED": {

   return {
     ...state,
     fetching: false,
     fetched: true,
     media: action.payload.map(m => new Media(m)),
   }
```

Comment: Oki, I was looking more to handle this inside `componentWillReceiveProps`, it is not the issue with delay, but if the array itself is empty in database.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you.